# How to encode only all special characters in PercentEncoding is swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, urlencode

I am running the code from similar questions from stackoverflow to percentage encode only  all the special characters(@!#$%^&*()~-_=+;:'/.,<>{}[])(not encoding alphanumeric characters) on xcode playground . Here are my attempts

```
          import UIKit
    
    //////////////
    //Attempt 1
    var originalString = "Test@123!#$%^&*()~-_=+;:'/.,<>{}[]"
    
    let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
    
    print("Attemp 1:",escapedString)
    ///////////////////
    //Attempt 2
    func encodeValue(_ string: String) -> String? {
        guard let unescapedString = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ":/").inverted) else { return nil }
    
        return unescapedString
    }
    
    let encodedString = encodeValue("Test@123!#$%^&*()~-_=+;:'/.,<>{}[]")
    print("Attemp 2:",encodedString)
    //////////////////////
    //Attempt 3
    extension String {
        var encoded: String? {
            return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
        }
    }
    
    
    let encodedUrl = "Test@123!#$%^&*()~-_=+;:'/.,<>{}[]".encoded
    print("Attemp 3:",encodedUrl)
        //////////////
    //Attempt 4
    let myurlstring = "Test@123!#$%^&*()~-_=+;:'/.,<>{}[]"
    let urlwithPercentEscapes = myurlstring.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    print("Attemp 4:",urlwithPercentEscapes)

//////////////
//Attempt 5
var s = "Test@123!#$%^&*()~-_=+;:'/.,<>{}[]"
let encodedLink = s.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)
let encodedURL = NSURL(string: encodedLink!)! as URL
print("Attemp 5:",encodedURL)
```

Here are the results

> Attemp 1:
> Optional("Test@123!%23$%25%5E&*()~-_=+;:'/.,%3C%3E%7B%7D%5B%5D")
>
> Attemp 2: Optional("Test@123!#$%^&*()~-_=+;%3A'%2F.,<>{}[]")
>
> Attemp 3:
> Optional("Test%40123!%23$%25%5E&*()~-_=+;%3A'%2F.,%3C%3E%7B%7D%5B%5D")
>
> Attemp 4:
> Optional("Test@123!%23$%25%5E&*()~-_=+;:'/.,%3C%3E%7B%7D%5B%5D")
>
> Attemp 5: Test@123!%23$%25%5E&*()~-_=+;:'/.,%3C%3E%7B%7D%5B%5D

Non of them are percentage encoding the complete special characters.I want to encode all of the special character just like  following special character are never encoded in almost all attempts.

> *()~-_=+;:'/.,

Kindly tell me the code to percentage encode all of my special character including *()~-_=+;:'/.,   ? Thanks

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want the resulting string to be "Test@123!" followed by percent encoding of everything else? Or "Test%40123" followed by %21 ... ?

Comment: I want "Test percentage encoding of @ 123 followed by percent encoding of everything else "?

Comment: alphanumeric-characters should remain same only special-character are need to be converted into percentage encoding

Comment: I had kind of similar requirements in c++, where I had to encode every special/unsafe character except alphanumeric and a few special characters ("-", ".", "_", "~"). you need to encode the individual component of the URL (as I did for query strings).   You may get some idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/q/69149676/5685911
I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To percent-encode everything except alphanumerics, pass `.alphanumerics` as the allowed characters:

```
let encoded = s.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
```

For your example this returns (as an Optional):

```sh
Test%40123%21%23%24%25%5E%26%2A%28%29%7E%2D%5F%3D%2B%3B%3A%27%2F%2E%2C%3C%3E%7B%7D%5B%5D
```

I assume this what you were looking for.

This isn't particularly useful, since this is unlikely to correctly encode any particular URL (which is what you seem to be doing). But if you have the need you describe (which is unrelated to correctly encoding URLs), then that's how you do it.

If you want to correctly encode URLs, construct the URL using [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents). It'll encode each piece using the rules for that piece. There is no simple string substitution that will correctly percent-encode an URL.