# What characters should I encode always?

Tags: c++, http, url, character-encoding

Trying to encode the URL before the HTTP call but getting no response from the server (response code 0). Without encoding things working fine.

**Requirement**:

Need to encode special characters in URL. Specifically, I need to encode the below characters plus any other such characters:

! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]

**This is my understanding of Url Encoding:**

Only alphanumeric and a few special characters ("-", ".", "_", "~")  may be used unencoded within a URL. The rest of the characters transmitted as part of the URL, whether in the query string or path segment, must always be encoded. [Reference](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986).

I am doubtful on "*", as in Android this can also go unencoded. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder)

I tried encoding the whole URL, as well as individual params, but I'm getting the same result.

Below is my encoding function:

```
void Url::escape(String& str)
{
    if(str.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }
    uint32_t i = 0;
    unsigned char in;
    char hexbuf[4];

    while(i < str.size())
    {
        in = static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i]);

        switch(in)
        {
            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9': case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f': case 'g': case 'h': case 'i': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l': case 'm': case 'n': case 'o': case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': case 't': case 'u': case 'v': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z': case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': case 'D': case 'E': case 'F': case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': case 'J': case 'K': case 'L': case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S': case 'T': case 'U': case 'V': case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z': case '_': case '~': case '.': case '-':
                break;
            default:
                str[i] = '%';
                snprintf(hexbuf, 3, "%02X", in);
                str.insert(hexbuf, i + 1);
                i += 2;
                break;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything here? I want clarity on below as well:

1. Can I call `Url::escape()` on the whole input url String, or should I encode individual query params only?
2. What characters can/should I omit in encoding (is `Url::escape()` correct or not)?

I referred to multiple references here, but I could not find any concrete solution.

Comment: First step would be to check the actual HTTP request that you are sending. Does something actually get sent? What library are you using?

Comment: @JulianReschke, Yes, as stated in the question I have checked this as 1st step. No issue with the HTTP requests. And I am not using any library. I am using my own encoding method as mentioned. I am new to C++ and could not found any library like Java or Android for which I am used to.

Comment: @Akki "I am new to C++ and could not found any library like Java or Android for which I am used to" - there are TONS of 3rd party HTTP libraries for C and C++, such as [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/), etc. This is not a task you should be coding from scratch, as HTTP is actually a fairly complex protocol, especially once you start dealing with things like HTTPS, HTTP/2, etc. All of the hard work has already been done, so you should leverage that effort.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, I was referring to the encoding part in the Url before I could pass it on to the Http. I doubt that we can pass anything without encoding it to the Http and it will take care of it. My requirement is simple: I need to encode the special characters in the Url such as ! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ], etc. before I create the HTTP request object.

Comment: @akki - I'm downvoting questions that simply do not contain sufficient information for anybody to help.

Comment: @JulianReschke, I think I have provided sufficient information. And on your comment, I have commented the same. Anyways, I found my answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Can I call Url::escape() on whole input url String or should I go by encoding indivisual query param only?

You must encode individual components of the url, not just the query params.

> 2. What characters I can/should omit in encoding (is Url::escape() is correct or not)?

Different components have different rules of what characters need to be encoded and which ones do not.

[RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) outlines the basic rules that all URLs have to conform to. However, there are [lots of URL schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes), many of which provide additional rules/restrictions on top of this syntax for scheme-specific components, and have their own RFCs.

Comment: I have encoded values in my query component (having special/unsafe characters) with the same custom method as I have mentioned in my question and it worked well. My query strings have multiple key-value pairs and Initially, I was not encoding some values correctly. But now it worked. Thanks